# Apache Kafka partition re-assignment upon full cluster restart reg

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster of 3 nodes. I want to add 2 more nodes to the cluster to make it 5 node cluster.
After adding the nodes, I will do a FULL CLUSTER RESTART. i.e., shutdown all kafka & zookeeper services at once and then start all the services in 5 nodes.

I want to know
1. Does the FULL CLUSTER RESTART distribute the topic partitions evenly across 5 nodes?
Or need to run the partition reassignment tool kafka-reassign-partitions.sh ?
2. Doesn't Kafka have internal mechanism to automatically reassign the partitions unless running kafka-reassign-partitions.sh

Please clarify. Thank you.

Comment: When adding a new node to the cluster, it is not necessary to restart the existing nodes of the kafka and zookeeper.  

Only new topics will be placed evenly across all brokers, old ones need to be balanced by hand

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not rebalance the partitions across nodes. You will need to do this manually. Kafka will rebalance *consumers* when a new consumer joins a consumer group but that is something totally different.

If you are running the full Confluent stack you can use the confluent-rebalance tool to do it.

Comment: I tried the reassign partition tool and seen its not reliable.

The problem with reassign partition tool kafka-reassign-partitions.sh is: it takes huge time in re-balancing each partition and during this time the entire cluster performance is impacted.

When I ran this tool, it was stuck with one partition and it hung there for more than a day.
The Cluster performance was severely impacted, and we had to restart the entire cluster.

I don't see a way even to stop the tool when its taking long time.

Can you please suggest how to overcome this situations.